# have pictures scroll sideways

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a line of pictures stay within one line and than scroll sideways using overflow: scroll; however whatever I do the items keep going underneath eachother.

```
<div class="portfolio_row">
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="portfolio1.jpg"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="portfolio2.jpg"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="portfolio1.jpg"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="portfolio2.jpg"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.portfolio_row {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.portfolio_item {
    float: left;
}

.portfolio_item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    .portfolio_item {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
    .portfolio_item {
        width: 33%;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the pictures to stay in one line and scroll sideways instead of having them go underneath eachother?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block` instead of float. And also no need for `width` property on the container.

```css
.portfolio_row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.portfolio_item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio_item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
  .portfolio_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
  .portfolio_item {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio_row">
  <div class="portfolio_item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio_item">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `float: left` inside your `portfolio_item` class use `display: inline-block` to align your images

```css
.portfolio_row {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.portfolio_item {
    display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio_item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 950px) {
    .portfolio_item {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
    .portfolio_item {
        width: 33%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio_row">
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7731571.ece/ALTERNATES/s298/Pokemon-charmander.png"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7731571.ece/ALTERNATES/s298/Pokemon-charmander.png"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7731571.ece/ALTERNATES/s298/Pokemon-charmander.png"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio_item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7731571.ece/ALTERNATES/s298/Pokemon-charmander.png"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```